# How to search all issues with inconsistent priority workflows

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm looking to conduct a JQL search query to obtain a list of issues across a multitude of projects based on a label and priority. The challenge is that some of the projects have their own custom workflow which has different priorities... example "triage" is one of the projects priorities listed.

I've attempted a multitude of different queries trying to get it to function properly, using high, highest, 1 - highest, critical, etc.. and have been unable to obtain those tickets.. I'm wanting to obtain a consistent way to obtain all tickets of a mutual critical or high statuses via a singular JQL query without context of those projects and custom prioritizations.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

JQL is a half-arsed implementation of SQL at best, mainly designed to prevent SQL Injection attacks into Jira. Don't get me wrong, it works well and serves it's purpose. But don't expect it to be a logic engine for you.

When you are wanting to essentially normalise "Priority" between projects, in traditional SQL you are talking hundreds of lines of SQL to standardise dumb decisions in an organisation. Jira isn't designed for this.

Jira controls dumb via Company Managed Projects VS Team Managed Projects.